# Jaxb generate classes from xsd:s with common include fails

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to generate classes from a bunch of xsd:s that all include the same common schema which simplified looks something like this:

Schema1.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="namespace">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
.....
</xsd:schema>
```

Schema2.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="namespace">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
.....
</xsd:schema>
```

and the common schema does not define a targetNamespace

Now when I try generating my classes using:

```
xjc -extension -episode episode.xjb -p se.test -encoding UTF-8 -mark-generated Schema1.xsd Schema2.xsd
```

I get an error saying: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class

Which point to the same line number in the common schema. Is there any way of getting around this problem. If I leave out the package parameter everything works fine but I would like to specify my own package.

Comment: Can you use different target namespaces for your XSDs?

Comment: No, I can't change the XSDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was actually that one of the XSDs (I have like 60 of them so I didn't look at each in detail...) was missing its namespace.

Gonna contact the supplier of the XSDs and ask them to fix it.